# GWT Server Request Methods not being called when passing through a SuperType Proxy class (Polymorphism)

Tags: java, gwt

I have a parent proxy:

`@ProxyFor(Parent.class)
public interface ParentProxy extends ValueProxy`

And a child proxy:

`@ProxyFor(Child.class)
public interface ChildProxy extends ParentProxy`

I have a RequestContext class with Request Methods:

```
@Service(value = RequestClass.class, locator = SpringServiceLocator.class)
@ExtraTypes({ChildProxy.class})
public interface PerformRequest extends RequestContext {    
    Request<Long> doSomeCalculation(List<ParentProxy> list)
}
```

I also have the server implementation of the Request class

```
public interface RequestClass {
   Long doSomeCalculation(List<Parent> list);
}

public class RequestClassImplementation implements RequestClass {

   public Long doSomeCalculation(List<Parent> list) {
     //implementation and return value here
   }
}
```

I then make a request (simplified)

```
//listOfParentProxy is a populated list
getRequestClass().doSomeCalculation(listOfParentProxy).to(MyReceiver);
```

And expect a response in the receiver

```
Receiver<Long> MyReceiver(){
return new Receiver<Long>() {
 @Override
  public void onSuccess(Long response) {
        //handle success
  }


 @Override
  public void onFailure(ServerFailure error){
      //handle failure
  }
}
```

My issue is that if I perform a request where my list of ParentProxies is populated, then my server method (doSomeCalculation) is not even called. I go straight into the onFailure method with a server error. However if I perform this request and pass in a null object or an empty list, then my server method is called and I end up in OnSuccess. Is there something I am forgetting when passing "Parent proxies" through a Request?

Comment: Do you really have **zero** error message?

Comment: Server side - I am not getting anything from debugging due to server methods not being called. If I debug the client side using super dev mode in google chrome, when it reaches the onFailure method I get a generic POST 500 (Internal Server Error).  The error also indicates that "the request could not be understood by the server due to malformed syntax"

Comment: Zero message in server logs? How about a breakpoint in the [`ExceptionHandler`](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/web/bindery/requestfactory/server/DefaultExceptionHandler.html)?